# CloudWatch Subscription Filter: using lambda or direct subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am exploring CloudWatch Logs streams to Firehose. As I understand so far, Cloudwatch Subscription Filter is an event that triggers a lambda to digest the CloudWatch logs and send it to a different destination (ElasticSearch or Firehose or ... another custom lambda). Please correct me if I am wrong.

My concern at the case Cloudwatch Logs Stream to Firehose are:

1/ In term of performance + pricing, is there any difference between :

- Cloudwatch Subscription Filter -> Firehose
- Cloudwatch Subscription Filter -> Lambda -> Firehose

2/ Which data format does Firehose received from Cloudwatch?

- Cloudwatch Subscription Filter -> Firehose : I don't know
- Cloudwatch Subscription Filter -> Lambda -> Firehose : I think lambda can transform the logs to JSON then put it to Firehose.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to send the logs to a firehose?

Comment: @ MyStackRunnethOver just to build a log analytics

Comment: I see. Make sure to take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html, if you haven't already :)

Comment: It really depends if you plan to collect logs from multiple accounts.
`Cloudwatch Subscription Filter -> Kinesis -> Firehose -> Lambda` , Firehose supports lambda trigger so you don't need Lambda infront the firehose. You definitely need lambda if you try some classification or custom processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. In term of performance + pricing, is there any difference between [having a lambda vs. going straight to firehose?] :

Yes. In terms of performance, you would see slightly greater latency as your data has to pass through a lambda before making it to the firehose, but very likely the increase would not matter at all. You would gain the flexibility of having a customizable processing step fronting your firehose - an opportunity to perform additional transformation or smarter filtering.

NB, you would **lose** CloudWatch's automatic compression when sending straight to firehose - if you wanted compression, you'd have to set it up yourself (probably on the firehose). Also, you would be paying for lambda invocations to process the intermediate step. [Check the pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) to see whether this actually matters.

> 2. Which data format does Firehose receive from Cloudwatch?

When going straight to firehose, you'd get [firehose's output configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html#format) (a bunch of records appended together in a file), where each record is a CloudWatch logs output:

```
{
    "owner": "123456789012",
    "logGroup": "CloudTrail",
    "logStream": "123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1",
    "subscriptionFilters": [
        "Destination"
    ],
    "messageType": "DATA_MESSAGE",
    "logEvents": [
        {
            "id": "31953106606966983378809025079804211143289615424298221568",
            "timestamp": 1432826855000,
            "message": "{\"eventVersion\":\"1.03\",\"userIdentity\":{\"type\":\"Root\"}"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

(Taken from [the SubscriptionFilter docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample))

When going to a lambda:

> The actual payload that Lambda receives is in the following format { "awslogs": {"data": "BASE64ENCODED_GZIP_COMPRESSED_DATA"} }

(Also from the docs linked above)

Where `data` is the (encoded, compressed) CloudWatch output object above.

Given that you write the lambda, you can output *whatever you want* to firehose. Keep in mind that firehose will do that same thing as above, appending multiple records into each output file.

---

A word of caution: [make sure to scale your firehose appropriately](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/limits.html) - if you're not careful, and you are under-scaled, firehose `put`s will start failing and you will start dropping log data. Make sure you're monitoring failures!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your very detailed answer, just a small concern, (maybe my confusion): the pricing is the same for both ways (having a lambda & going straight to firehose)?

Comment: "Also, you would be paying for lambda invocations to process the intermediate step." Lambda has a generous monthly free tier, so it depends on whether you're processing enough records to exceed it. Otherwise, the other things that could affect pricing are 1. if you use the lambda to filter more, your firehose costs would go down, and 2. it may be that putting compression on your firehose is more expensive than using the built-in cloudwatch streams compression when sending to firehose, because firehose charges based on input data volume in GB